# My RAM is not working at full speed

Tags: memory, speed

I just built my PC. I have the x470 gaming plus motherboard and 2x8GB COrsair Vengeance LPX 3000 MHz ram. It is only working on 2133 MHz. Is there anything that can be done to get the speeds up? Thanks.
[image]

Comment: What is your processor (this CPU type is cut of in the image)?

Comment: I can see two XMP profiles in the bottom of the pic, have you enabled any of them?

Comment: Processor is ryzen 2600x 4.05 Ghz. And what do you mean by xmp profiles?

Comment: I mean I see they are there. Not sure how to turn them on

Comment: Have a look at your Mainboard manual for this. Look for anything related to "Memory".

Comment: Okay I got it it was in the top of the screen. Works now. Put it as an answer and I will select it :) thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, for example, you have a [AMD Ryzen™ 5 2600 Processor](https://www.amd.com/en/products/cpu/amd-ryzen-5-2600) installed in your mainboard, you can set your RAM speed up to 2933 Mhz (see "System Memory Specification").

So select the appropriate memory profile in the UEFI BIOS.
Here it would be the *XMP Profile 2* with

```
DDR4 2933MHz 15-17-17-35
```

which would be the maximum that you can achieve with this CPU.
The maximum speed varies with the CPU installed.